# Record TV channel stream using RED5 media server?

Tags: rtsp, red5, recording, wowza

I want to record live TV channel stream. I know, in wowza media server, you can re-stream rtsp stream (for TV channel) and record using HTTPLiveStreamRecord addon.
Can I do such recording using RED5 media server? If yes, how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you by using Flash with NetStream object . The oflademo is an example of this.

Comment: Yes But using red5 you can extend the media server with java to do what you want. Also you dont have to pay money for it.